# Best practice to store and query likes/dislikes of a post in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app where users can like and dislike posts. Now, in firestore, I am creating a `liked_by` and `disliked_by` collections inside each `post` document, where I add the userId of the users who liked/disliked a post as document IDs.

Now, when showing posts to a user in the app, I have to check if each post has been liked or disliked by the current user, so that I show them that they have already liked/dislike the post. This means I have to perform 3 queries for every post (one for the post contents, one to check if the user's ID is in the list of the liked_by collection, and another to check if the user's ID is in the list of the disliked_by collection). That seems like too many queries per post, especially considering that the likelihood of the user actually having liked/disliked a post that they're seeing is low.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Other options I have thought about:

1. Keeping the liked/disliked list of user IDs in an array field within the post document. The downside here is that a post document will be too much text data when fetching, and also documents have a limit of 1MB so it's not fully scalable.
2. Creating a liked/disliked collections in each `users` document and keep a list of post IDs that a user has liked/disliked. The one downside here is that overtime this list of documents will grow and I'll have to always fetch all documents every time at first. So if the user has liked/disliked 300 posts overtime, then from that point forward, i'll always fetch all 300 documents to see if a post they are looking at is within the list. If they only ended up looking at 30 posts, then this wouldn't be worth it, I could've queried the likes/dislikes separately and only fetched 90 documents (3 queries for each post as mentioned in second paragraph), instead of the 300 plust the 30 posts.

Thanks

Comment: What is 'too many queries per post'? A query for a single piece of data per collection doesn't seem like a lot to me - you're simply checking to see if the uid exists in either collection (liked or disliked), right? I assume you're storing something like the documentId being the uid and a child field `liked: true`? You could probably reduce that by storing it with the uid as the document id and child field of `status:` with values`liked` or `disliked`. Then, just read that documentId and if it fails, it was neither liked nor disliked. If it succeeds, it will either be liked or disliked.

Comment: @Jay I just thought that it was inefficient to make three queries to fetch one post, of course "too many" is relative. I like your idea though to reduce it to two queries instead. Thanks, I'll explore that more.

Comment: It's really only one read and not even a query. Since you know the path, just get the document at that path. If it fails it doesn't exist. If it passed you will also have the liked or disliked data. So it's all done with just one read.